# hiding keyboard returning null pointer

Tags: android, crash, keyboard

I just received fabric mail that my app crashed and I test it on my mobile but it's working fine but I don't why it crashes on OS 9.

```
context = this;
RelativeLayout parentView = findViewById(R.id.relative_cusweb_parent); 
setupParent(parentView);
```

Above is my **onCreate** method & **relative_cusweb_parent** is main relative layout of CustomWeb Class.

```
private void setupParent(View view) {
    if (!(view instanceof EditText)) {
        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                hideKeyboard();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            View innerView = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);
            setupParent(innerView);
        }
    }
}

private void hideKeyboard() {
    input.clearFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) 
    {
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(Objects.requireNonNull(getCurrentFocus()).getWindowToken(), 0); // here a is crashing
    }
}
```

App is crashing on this line

```
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(Objects.requireNonNull(getCurrentFocus()).getWindowToken(), 0);
```

and below is the log

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
   at codeline.onlinebills.activities.CustomWeb.hideKeyboard(CustomWeb.java:222)
   at codeline.onlinebills.activities.CustomWeb.access$200(CustomWeb.java:38)
   at codeline.onlinebills.activities.CustomWeb$4.onTouch(CustomWeb.java:231)
   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12611)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3035)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2714)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3041)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2671)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's crashing because it doesn't find any view in focus and getCurrentFocus() returns null.

> added in API level 1
>
> public abstract View getCurrentFocus ()
>
> Return the view in this Window that currently has focus, or null if there are none. Note that this does not look in any containing Window.
> ([source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window#getCurrentFocus()))

Replace this:

```
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(Objects.requireNonNull(getCurrentFocus()).getWindowToken(), 0);
```

with this:

```
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide keyboard with this method :

```
private void hideKeyBoard()
{
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if( imm != null )
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your hideKeyboard method with the code below, I am using this is my app to  hide the Keyboard and it works perfectly:

```
private void hideKeyboard() {
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
}
```